# when compile this code only show scores of last input

Tags: java

when compile this code only show scores of last input

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class TestII {
    static Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in);
    static int countNa = 0;
    static int countSc = 0;
    static int numSc;
    static int numNa;
    static int [] scores = null;
    static String [] names = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many name and scores");
        System.out.print("N> ");
        numNa = key.nextInt();
        System.out.print("S> ");
        numSc = key.nextInt();
        names = new String [numNa]; 
        scores = new int [numSc];
        readNameScores( );
        showNamesScores ();
    }
    public static void readNameScores (){
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            countNa++;
            System.out.print("Name "+countNa+": ");
            names [i] = key.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++){
                countSc++;

                    if (countSc > scores.length){
                        countSc = 0;
                        countSc++;
                    }
                System.out.print("\tScore "+countSc+": ");
                scores [j] = key.nextInt();
                }
            }
    }
    public static void showNamesScores (){
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            System.out.print(names [i]+"\t");
            for (int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++){
                System.out.print(scores [j]+"   ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sample of output

How many name and scores
N> 2
S> 2
Name 1: max
    Score 1: 2
    Score 2: 4
Name 2: mike
    Score 1: 3
    Score 2: 2

max 3   2   mike    3   2

Answer (score 0):

Your `scores` array is make to hold the scores of just a single name. You should change it to a 2D array.

```
static int [][] scores = null;
...
names = new String [numNa]; 
scores = new int [numNa][numSc];
...
public static void readNameScores (){
  for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    System.out.print("Name "+(i+1)+": ");
    names [i] = key.next();
    for (int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++){
        System.out.print("\tScore "+(j+1)+": ");
        scores[i][j] = key.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: and if more than two names and scores  ?

Comment: @PouriaMohseni Same code should work, as long as each name has the same number of scores.